# HP Pavilion dv4-1225dx Sound Driver

Tags: audio, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavilion dv4-1225dx with Win7 32 bit. I went to the HP drivers page at http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-75078-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4062&product=3860437&sw_lang= and installed the sound driver (**IDT High-Definition Audio CODEC Driver** according to HP support page). Win7 gave me one of those "this program may have not been installed correctly" notices and I can't get sound still.

Is there another driver/program I could use to get sound?

Thank you.

Comment: that looks like the right driver to me as well.  Did you try that one more than once? (Perhaps download it again).

Comment: I tried reinstalling several times and I am so puzzled as to why it won't work.

Comment: When you click the volume icon in Windows does it show an audio device or does it say that no audio devices are installed (but they are through `Device Manager`)? Additionally, try uninstalling the devices (and tick to delete the files) -> restart -> see if Windows install -> if it doesn't then try a Windows update.